# date formatting in php

Tags: php, date

I have a string as mentioned below:

```php
$ts  = "3/11/09 11:18:59 AM";
```

which I got using the `date()` function.

Now I need to convert this to a readable format like below

```
11-Mar-2009
```

I have tried everything using `date()`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it to something you can use for further formatting. [strtotime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a good start, which yields a unix timestamp. You can format that one using [strftime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) then.

```
strftime("%d-%b-%G", strtotime($ts));
```

Comment: True, It doesn't work on *every* installation - there are windows builds with this function, though. You can use date() instead, if you want to.

Comment: @Vadim: Which PHP for Windows installs doesn't it work under?  strftime() is a wrapper over the C call of the same name, which is a standard part of time.h.  As I recall, date() is also a wrapper over strftime(), but does more for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you initially get the string from the date() function, then pass on formatting arguments to the date-function instead:

date('Y-m-d')

instead of converting the string once again.

EDIT: If you need to keep track of the actual timestamp, then store it as a timestamp:

```
  
// Store the timestamp in a variable. This is just an integer, unix timestamp (seconds since epoch)
$time = time();

// output ISO8601 (maybe insert to database? whatever) 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $time);

// output your readable format
echo date('j-M-Y', $time);
```

Using strtotime() is convinient but unessecary parsing and storage of a timerepresentation is a stupid idea.

Comment: Thats not an option as I need to get the time as well.
Only while I am displaying I need in the mentioned format

Comment: You should keep the date in an easily used format for the computer itself, not as a string. the return of the time() method is a good start, and then pass that variable as the 2nd argument to date() for formatting. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I tried doing this and it worked.

```
echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime($ts));
```

Comment: I would recommend this over the current answer as it works in Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date() function to generate the required format directly, like so:

```
date("j-M-Y");
```

See [www.php.net/date](http://www.php.net/date) for all the possible formats of the output of the date() function.

Comment: Thats not an option as I need to get the time as well.
Only while I am displaying I need in the mentioned format