# Formatting a DATE value

Tags: php, date

In my mySQL database, I have a DATE value in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". In my PHP web-page, I retrieve the value from the database and write it to the HTML output. However, I would like to change the formatting of that value.

Example:

```
"2012-02-01"
```

I would like to output:

```
"February 1, 2012"
```

Is there a built-in PHP-function which can achieve that, or do I have to write my own function for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638011/date-formatting-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php),

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime("2012-02-01"));
```

Although it's probably better to use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) instead of [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) so that it's unambiguous,

```
date("F j, Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2012));
```

Comment: I've got the DATE value directly from my mySQL database (where it's stored as a DATE value). `strtotime()` appears to understand this value, so I'm fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked thru the PHP documentation?

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: No. I've only started working with PHP recently, so I haven't yes familiarized myself with the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
strftime("%B %e, %Y", strtotime("2012-02-01"));
```